# updating of image while reading from directory

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i want to update  displayed image over loop, i am working in google colab, therefore my code is based on google colab

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
from PIL import Image
import glob
import time
from pylab import *
for filename in glob.iglob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/*.jpg'):
  #print(filename)
  img = array(Image.open(filename))
  imshow(img)
  time.sleep(2)
```

but it displays only one image, how can i make so that image will be updated automatically?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think Ipython display and clear_output may help with the animation:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import time
from pylab import *
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

for filename in glob.iglob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/*.jpg'):
  clear_output(wait=True)
  img = array(Image.open(filename))
  display(imshow(img))
  plt.axis("off")
  plt.show()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: sorry i have seen  answer right know, what i want is to animate image on display

Comment: @datodatuashvili could you please share your solution to help me know what your mean by "animate image on display"?

Comment: by animate i meant  images should be displayed   one by one on  the same plot  after several second

Comment: Thank you, @datodatuashvili. Could you please share your solution here? I would like to learn from you.

Comment: i still dont have solution :D :D

Comment: Hi @datodatuashvili, I think Ipython `display` and `clear_output` may help with animation that you meant. I have tried and it worked for me. I edited the code, please try it again.

Comment: Let me check it   and i will response  soon